# How to make selected html tag highlighting in Visual Studio 2010 work like it did in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ide

Is there a way to make VS 2010 work more like VS 2008 when it come to highlighting the begin and end tags of the currently selected html element.

In Visual Studio 2008 the selected html tag simply gets a bold font on the beginning and end tags of the element along with the < > characters, and the attributes remain normal.

The only option I can seem to find in VS 2010 is to highlight the entire selected tag, attributes and all.  I have found nothing that just controls the selected tag itself.

Anyone know a way to make it work more like the old editor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors. Then select Brace Matching(Rectangle), set the item background to the same background your ide is using and also check the bold option. That should do it.

Comment: You would think that would work or at least do something.  I have tried this, and it doesn't even make the text bold, it only gets rid of the background.  Does it work on your's? I have service pack 1 installed.

Comment: You are correct, it seems that selecting bold doesn't do anything. Might be a bug then. Sorry wouldn't know any other way to do this besides maybe through an extension.

Comment: Oh well.  I guess I will get used to  the whole thing being highlighted.  It's not so bad for the small tags, but when you have a server control with a lot of attributes spread out over a few lines then it is not that useful.  Their is another highlight brace color setting the one that doesn't say rectangle, but I have yet to find where that is being applied.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors. Then select Highlighted Reference. Change the Item background.

This works in VS2015 - I'm not sure about other versions of VS.